# Accessing a MySql database from external IP (Docker containers)

Tags: mysql, database, bash, docker, phpmyadmin

Using ***Docker containers***, I am trying to access a **MySQL Docker container** (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) from other containers.

To do that, I've been using the PhpMyAdmin docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) which is the most simple way to view mysql databases.

## Access denied

However... my phpmyadmin container cannot connect to the mysql container, giving the following error :

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.7' (using password:
> YES)

## This is the config I have used for the mysql container:

docker run --name mysql001 -v /path/to/volumes/mysql001:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234  -p 33067:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server:latest --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci

The phpmyadmin configuration is:

docker run --name phpmyadmin1 -d --link mysql001:db -p 3949:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234

## Failed attempts

I've tried to log on in bash mode with `docker exec -i mysql001 bash` and run mysql commands from here, but each time I try for example to do `mysql -u root -p` so I get rejected with "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

What did I miss?

Comment: The issue looks to be with the hostname and so the --hostname flag when trying to get into mysql. Without a host name specified, the mysql command will just assume the host name to be localhost. I'm guessing there is another parameter to pass for the host name when starting the container in the first place. This isn't really a bash query though.

Comment: I think a part of this problem may be the default security option that restricts the access to the localhost only, however I have not found where to change it... but the fact that I can't log in it even with bash (so technically I should be considered to be querying from localhost) with the provided password is strange.